# Run-time error with For Loop in class method - Data Structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

So I'm supposed to create a code that has a container class that stores a collection of strings. The class should have 3 public members: a constructor that initializes an empty collection, an insert function that adds one string to the collection, and a function that receives a data/string value and returns one of the data values (string/word) in the collection - specifically, the value whose signature is numerically closest to the parameter's signature. Note: The class should *not* store signatures of all of the data (it should calculate as needed, using a private method).

Also, the code should include an analysis function that analyzes the worst-case running time of the method/function that finds the data near the given signature. Needs the exact total count (as a closed-form function of n - the number of strings in the container) of data (string) operations, possibly including read/writes (in RAM, not I/O), comparisons and arithmetic operations. In this case, array/vector indices are not "data" - only string accesses/operations are of interest. Finally, an O-notation function should be included to describe the exact count.

So far, my code includes the 3 public members and the private method to calculate signatures. I've managed to iron out a couple of run-time errors along the way, but I've still got a couple more that I'm having trouble with. Specifically, it looks like I'm getting a run-time error where I'm triggering a breakpoint with my For loop in the compareData function. I'm almost certain it has something to do with how I've gone about initializing the nearestValue variable and the nextValue variable, but I'm not quite sure the specific issue.

If anyone here can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and/or any other logic or run-time errors my code has so far, I would greatly appreciate it. Furthermore, if someone could help me with formulating the analysis function to figure out the requested running time (specifically in O-notation), that would be great too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class stringCollection
{
    public:
        stringCollection(); 
        void addString(); 
        int compareData(string newString); 
    private:
        int calcSignature(string inp); 
        string userInput;
};

stringCollection::stringCollection()
{
    vector <string> useInp;
}

void stringCollection::addString()
{
    vector<string> useInp; //make vector a private variable and then reference it here instead?
    string insert;
    int i = 0;

    while (1) 
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a string.\nEnter as many as you want.\nWhen you're finished, type 'no more': \n\n" << endl;
        getline(cin, insert);

        if (insert == "no more")
            break;
    }

    useInp.push_back(insert);

}

int stringCollection::compareData(string newString)
{ 
    vector<string> useInp;
    int index = 0;
    int nearestValue = calcSignature(useInp[index]);
    int nextValue = calcSignature(useInp[index + 1]);
    int newSignature;

    newSignature = calcSignature(newString);

    for (string::size_type index = 0; index < useInp.size(); ++index)
    {
        if ((abs(nearestValue - newSignature)) > (abs(nextValue - newSignature)))
            nearestValue = nextValue;
    }

    return nearestValue;
}

int stringCollection::calcSignature(string inp)
{
    int total = 0;

    for (string::size_type index = 0; index < inp.length(); ++index)
    {
        total = total * 2 + static_cast<int>(inp[index]);
    } 

    return total;
}

int main()
{
    stringCollection classCall;
    string newString;
    int nearestValue;

    classCall.addString(); 

    cout << "\,\n\n\nPlease enter one final string: " << endl;
    getline(cin, newString);

    nearestValue = classCall.compareData(newString);

    cout << "\n\nGood news! Of all the strings you entered previously,\n the one with the closest ASCII value to the\n last string you entered is: " << nearestValue << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int nearestValue = calcSignature(useInp[index]);` does not define a general relationship between `nearestValue` and `calcSignature`. It declares `nearestValue` as an `int` variable, and *initializes* it, once, with the value of the expression `calcSignature(useInp[index])`, calculated at that point in the execution.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. Part of this is about learning about expressing things in a programming language, and part of this is about tool usage and general techniques, such as using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually *storing* any `string`s in your container - in every function you create a new **local** `vector`, then throw it away at the end of the function, e.g.:

```
stringCollection::stringCollection() // <-- constructs the object
{
    vector <string> useInp; // <-- local, not class member
} // <-- local vector is destroyed, not kept!
```

Then you try to look inside an empty `vector` you only just created, with no content:

```
int stringCollection::compareData(string newString)
{ 
    vector<string> useInp;
    int index = 0;
    int nearestValue = calcSignature(useInp[index]);
        // trying to read something out of index 0, but the container is completely empty!!!
```

---

I believe you want the `vector` to be a member of your container class:

```
class stringCollection
{
    private:
    // data members:
    std::vector<std::string> storedStrings_;

    public:
        stringCollection(); 
        void addString(); 
        int compareData(string newString); 
    private:
        int calcSignature(string inp); 
        string userInput;
};
```

Then in `addString()`, remove the definition of `useInp`, and change the last line to `storedStrings_.push_back(insert);`.

---

Then whenever you read from `storedStrings_`, check `index < storedStrings_.size()` (not `<`, not `<=`).

You should probably also access the `vector` using `storedStrings_.at(index)` rather than `storedStrings_[index]`, as this does a range check for you and throws an exception if you acccess an element which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. You're definitely right about my vector which is part of why I included some more code now to print out the current number of elements in my vector so that I can be more informed about whether I'm inputting the elements correctly. So I made your suggested changes to my code, but I'm getting an "exception handled" message after running it again? I'm also getting an "exception thrown" message indicating a run-time error #0, which means the value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. Do you have any suggestions for where to go from here?

Comment: Also, if possible, do you have any suggestions about how to go about creating the "analysis" function my code needs to determine the worst-case running time that I mentioned at the beginning of my post? I'd really appreciate the help.